# Finding an equation relating the coordinates of a vector b in range of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is supposed to be\begin{bmatrix}1&3&0\\2&1&-2\\1&8&2\end{bmatrix}

after row reducing and getting it to row echelon form, i get

\begin{bmatrix}1&3&0\\0&-5&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

So I see my range is $[1,2,1]^T$  and $[3,1,8]^T$

and my dimension is 2 because I have two pivots

The second part of the question is asking to find an equation relating the coordinates of a vector b = $(b1,b2,b3)^T$ in range(A)

I'm not sure how exactly to do this, but this is what I did, I started off with

x$(1,2,1)^T$+y$(3,1,8)^T$ = $(b1,b2,b3)^T$

and after row reduction, i get

\begin{bmatrix}1&3&b1\\0&1&-(1/5)(b2-2b1)\\0&0&b3+b2-3b1\end{bmatrix}

I got lost at this point, I'm not sure what exactly I'm supposed to be doing with this matrix. How can I solve this part, and am I even doing it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

From the vectors in your  range $ [1,2,1]^T$ and $[3,1,8]^T$ you find the span of these two vectors.

Thus $ x= r+3s, y=2r+s, z= r+8s$

Solve the first two for $r$ and $s$ and plug the results in the  third one to get $$z=3x-y$$

Comment: thanks a lot, i think i understand it now, but I'm trying to do the math and i got r=x-3s and s = y - 2r = y - 2(x -3s) = y - 2x + 6s and when i plugged it in for z, i ended up getting z = (x - 3s) + 8(y - 2x + 6s) which gets me a completely different answer. How did you get z = 3x -y?

Comment: Solve the first two equations for  $r $ and  $s$  in terms of $x$ and $y$ alone,  and plug the results in the third one to get $z=3x-y$

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm still struggling with this. I solved for r in x = r + 3s and go r = x - 3s, then I solved for s in the second equation s = y - 2r and plugged in r into it to get s = y -2x + 6s. So I solved for x and y alone but plugging those into the last equation won't work.